# How do I reduce the space allocated to Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 , but now I am not satisfied as it has taken more space 100 GB. Since I have to use Windows more often, I found that I am unable to see the files of Ubuntu when I open the Window. Therefore I want to give smaller file system (repartition). Please guide me so that I can reduce the volume of my Ubuntu file system.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Live CD or a Live USB to run an app called GParted. A Live CD (or USB) is an installation CD (or USB), but when the option pops up, select "Try Ubuntu without installing".

Then, when the boot process is complete, run the GParted app from the Dash Menu. It will permit you to change the size of your disks.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed 12.04, did you choose the partition size, or did you leave it to the installer?? Anyway, if you run the partition tool called Gparted you will be able to see how your hard disc is split up, and also to resize the Ubuntu partition to suit your needs.
You may need to install Gparted from the Ubuntu Software Centre if it is not already in place.

Comment: This won't work since GParted cannot reduce a partition it is running from.

Comment: And if it could, it would be very dangerous and would probably produce terrible data loss. GParted should not be used to modify the partition table of the physical drive containing the partition out of which it is running. (You can use it to perform operations that don't involve changing the partition table, though, like changing a partition's volume name.)

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/liveusb.php) and/or [here](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) if you do not have/prefer flash drive.

Runs from flash drive so no partition is mounted and you can resize all.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.